# How to echo 2 rows of results to table with 2 columns

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using the below code to echo results from my table. However, the results produces new row upon each looping. But I want the first row data from database to echo in first column then move on to next column for next row of data. Simply said, refer to the picture here:
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvsc4.png)

What I want:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE category='other'");
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width=500><b>". $row->name . "</b><br/>Address: ". $row->address . "<br/>Phone no: ". $row->phoneno . "<br/>Fax No:". $row->faxno ."<br/>Email: ". $row->email . "<br/>Website: ". $row->website ."</td>";
        //echo "</tr>";
        //echo "<tr>";
        //fetch next object here
        echo "<td  width=500><b>". $row->name . "</b><br/>Address: ". $row->address . "<br/>Phone no: ". $row->phoneno . "<br/>Fax No:". $row->faxno ."<br/>Email: ". $row->email . "<br/>Website: ". $row->website ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: try my answers it give you what expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below coding will helpful.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
echo "<table border=1>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
    $i++;
    if($i % 2 == 1) {
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td width=500><b>". $row->name . "</b><br/>Address: ". $row->address . "<br/>Phone no: ". $row->phoneno . "<br/>Fax No:". $row->faxno ."<br/>Email: ". $row->email . "<br/>Website: ". $row->website ."</td>";
    if($i % 2 == 0) { 
        echo "</tr>";
    }    
}
if($i % 2 == 1) { // Used to prevent alignment issue while odd number of rows return
    echo "<td></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count and proceed like this :

```
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        if ($count%2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }


        echo "<td width=500><b>". $row->name . "</b><br/>Address: ". $row->address . "<br/>Phone no: ". $row->phoneno . "<br/>Fax No:". $row->faxno ."<br/>Email: ". $row->email . "<br/>Website: ". $row->website ."</td>";

        $remainder = $count%2;
        if ($remainder%2 == 1) {
             echo "</tr>";
        }
        $count++;

    }
```

Comment: I've tried but this give me the same result that display twice on each columns. (result 1 | result 1)

Comment: Now the output is only 1 column

Comment: Can you copy the code i edited now and give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

try my workout   its working like perfect what you expected result

```
    <?php

     $result =array('name','hi','hlo','as');

    if(!empty($result)) {

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    $i=0;

    foreach($result as $row)
    {

   //  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { //here use like this 

        if($i==0)
        {
           echo "<tr>";
        }

        echo '<td>'.$row.'</td>';

        //echo "<td><b>" . $row->name . "</b></td><td>Address: " . $row->address . "</td></tr><tr><td>Phone no: " . $row->phoneno . "</td><td>Fax No:" . $row->faxno . "</td></tr><tr><td>Email: " . $row->email . "</td><td>Website: " . $row->website .
       // "</td>";  //and your code here like this 


        if($i==1)
        {
            echo "</tr>";

            $i=-1;
        }



      $i++;


    }

    echo "</table>";

    }

    ?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    -----------
    |name | hi|
    -----------
    | hlo | as|
`   -----------
```

Comment: Your method required String data but I'm displaying the data from database so it didn't work

Comment: logically it works fine you have implement the code .

Comment: change echo "<td><b>" . $row->name . "</b></td><td>Address: " . $row->address . "</td></tr><tr><td>Phone no: " . $row->phoneno . "</td><td>Fax No:" . $row->faxno . "</td></tr><tr><td>Email: " . $row->email . "</td><td>Website: " . $row->website .
        "</td>";    insted of  echo '<td>'.$row.'</td>';

Comment: change  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) insted of foreach($result as $row)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the response. After getting some idea from the responses, I've managed to solve it by using the code below. I made changes by adding counter and start the  tag before php coding.

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>          

<?php
include("connect.php");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE category='other'");
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
         echo "<td width=500><b>". $row->name . "</b><br/>Address: ".  $row->address . "<br/>Phone no: ". $row->phoneno . "<br/>Fax No:". $row->faxno ."<br/>Email: ". $row->email . "<br/>Website: ". $row->website ."</td>";

         if($count % 2 == 0){
            //nothing here
         }

         else{
             echo "</tr>";
             echo "<tr>";
         }
         $count++;
   }
   echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: if $result->fetch_object() empty means creating half   table ? ha ha

Comment: @Annie Tan. It will not work every time perfectly. As jothi said if return rows empty or returning odd rows. Go through my code it will be handy.